# FIFO processing of Files added to a folder in Java

Tags: java, file-io

Is there any way in Java to ensure FIFO processing of files added to a folder. I am looking for a solution that is platform independent. I am currently using the `listFiles()` method in `java.io.File` to get all the files out of a directory, but I have read that it does not guarantee any order of files found using this method. I have also thought of sorting the Files based on their last modified date, but this is unreliable, and does not ensure FIFO. Does anyone have any other ideas perhaps?

I have to use Java 6, Java 7 is not an option.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a platform-independent manner. Some platforms change the file creation date when you move (or copy) them to a folder, others change the file modification date, others change the file access date, others change nothing at all. I don't think there is any reliable way to sort files in the order in which they were put in the folder.

Comment: I believe you are correct, unfortunately lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File.listFiles()` method returns the files in an unspecified platform dependent order.

If the files in the directory are not going to be changed as you are processing them, then sorting the `File` list should work.

If the files in the directory are liable to change, then there is no way that you can get a "snapshot" of the files and their modification times.  But you could potentially use a Java 7 [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to track directory additions and file changes, and use that to deal with changes that happen during and after the directory listing and sorting.

---

There no equivalent to the Java 7 WatchService in Java 6.  If you want that kind of thing you will either to use an external program to feed the file names to Java in the right order, or use JNI and native code to interact with to OS-level file / directory watching service.

Comment: Another requirement I should have mentioned (I will make the changes). I have to use Java 6. The files are not being modified in the directory. I am essentially looking for the files, then moving them somewhere else. There is nothing being modified in the files themselves by my program. Is there anything like a WatchService in Java 6?

Comment: There is going to be a constant flow of files added to the directory, and my program will be constantly moving the files.

Comment: OK ... with those constraints, there is no pure Java 6 solution.

Comment: Not a pure Java 6 solution, but there is http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/ which does basically the same as WatchService in Java 7.